# asp.net dynamic GridView SelectCommand paging/sorting throwing Oracle error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

**EDIT: Solved this myself with help from Felix (See answer below)**

I am trying to add some basic search/filtering functionality to a GridView using the SelectCommand. Upon changing a DropdownList and clicking a Button, the `SelectCommand` should change along with adding `SelectParameter`.

The problem is that once changing the `SelectCommand` and adding the appropriate `SelectParameter`, only the first page displays perfectly, showing the correct filtered results. Trying to change the page (or sorting) throws an Oracle error

> (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: ORA-01036:
>   illegal variable name/number).

When removing the filtering (thus reverting the SelectCommand and removing the SelectParameter) the paging/sorting works correctly.

---

.ascx code:

(Note that `owner_ddl` DropdownList is populated with values in a seperate codebehind method)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="owner_ddl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="*">All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
&emsp;
<asp:Button ID="filter_btn" runat="server" Text="Filter" OnClick="filter_btn_Click" />

<br />
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="workbasket_gv" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
 AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" PageSize="20"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="INCIDENT_ID" DataSourceID="sqlIncident"
 EmptyDataText="No incidents meet this criteria" Width="90%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Button" SelectText="View">
            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="INCIDENT_ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="INCIDENT_ID">
            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OWNER" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="OWNER">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TITLE" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="TITLE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE_RAISED" HeaderText="Date Raised" SortExpression="DATE_RAISED" DataFormatString="{0:g}">
            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" FirstPageText="&lt;&lt; First"
     LastPageText="Last &gt;&gt;" NextPageText="Next &gt;" PreviousPageText="&lt; Prev">
    </PagerSettings>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlIncident" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=dbmisc89_dbmisc89.w34.bmw.uk;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=W50XS001_W;Password=sales_2;"
 ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient" SelectCommand="SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void filter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (owner_ddl.SelectedValue != "*")
    {
        // Defined owner
        string sql = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OWNER=:OWNER ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        sqlIncident.SelectCommand = sql;
        ControlParameter param = new ControlParameter("OWNER", System.Data.DbType.String, "owner_ddl", "SelectedValue");
        sqlIncident.SelectParameters.Add(param);
    }
    else
    {
        // All owners (Remove variable)
        string sql = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        sqlIncident.SelectCommand = sql;
        sqlIncident.SelectParameters.Clear();
    }
    workbasket_gv.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by removing the `SelectParameter` and putting the `owner_ddl.SelectedValue` directly into the SQL String. Also added a Session variable to pass to itself on `DataBind` so the paging/sorting keeps the correct query.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((String)Session["sqlOwnerType"]))
        {
            if ((String)Session["sqlOwnerType"] == "specific")
                sqlIncident.SelectCommand = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OWNER='" + owner_ddl.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
            else if ((String)Session["sqlOwnerType"] == "all")
                sqlIncident.SelectCommand = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        }
    }
}

protected void filter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (owner_ddl.SelectedValue != "*")
    {
        // Defined owner

        string sql = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OWNER='" + owner_ddl.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        sqlIncident.SelectCommand = sql;

        Session["sqlOwnerType"] = "specific";
    }
    else
    {
        // All owners (Remove variable)
        string sql = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        sqlIncident.SelectCommand = sql;

        Session["sqlOwnerType"] = "all";
    }
    workbasket_gv.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check with this. I am not sure whether its the problem.  let me knw if its right...

```
if (owner_ddl.SelectedValue != "*")
    {
        // Defined owner

ControlParameter param = new ControlParameter("OWNER", System.Data.DbType.String, "owner_ddl", "SelectedValue");
        sqlIncident.SelectParameters.Add(param);


        string sql = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, OWNER, TITLE, DATE_RAISED FROM INCIDENT_TBL WHERE TITLE IS NOT NULL AND OWNER=:OWNER ORDER BY DATE_RAISED DESC";
        sqlIncident.SelectCommand = sql;

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't seem to make a difference, I still get the same problem.

Comment: why did u add this sepereate code. you can add parameter inside your sqldatasource...

Comment: I've removed the SelectParameter and tried putting `owner_ddl.SelectedValue` directly into the `sql` String, the problem now is that changing page loses the new `SelectCommand`, it immediately reverts back to the original `SelectCommand`. I guess this has something to do with the ViewState changing, will have look now...

Comment: Sorted it, added a Session variable to pass to itself on `DataBind` so it keeps the correct SQL. Problem solved! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [INCIDENT_ID] = @INCIDENT_ID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Table] ([INCIDENT_ID], [OWNER]) VALUES (@INCIDENT_ID, @OWNER)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ([OWNER] = @OWNER)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table] SET [OWNER] = @OWNER WHERE [INCIDENT_ID] = @INCIDENT_ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="INCIDENT_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="INCIDENT_ID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="OWNER" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="owner_ddl" Name="OWNER" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="OWNER" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="INCIDENT_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>



 protected void filter_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        workbasket_gv.DataBind();
    }
```